# Wagtail making pages expire

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, wagtail

Is there a management command or something I should be running to make wagtail pick up expired pages?

Example: I go into the admin dashboard and change the expiration time (not through the wagtail admin).

Wagtail doesn't pick up that this post becomes expired / change the expired boolean to True. Since this is a non-editable field that isn't changeable through admin. Yes, I can mke my own but I'm curious as to why wagtail doesn't pick this up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see `publish_scheduled_pages`:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/management_commands.html#publish-scheduled-pages

Comment: I tried that but whenever I run this management command it resets the time remaining to 1 hour for posts which are expired. Guess there's a bug somewhere in my code... I just tried this and a post which has the expire_at time set for 3 days ago has `expired = False` after running the command. Do these required page revision objects to exist?

Comment: NEvermind it requires the page to be live + expired time to be less than the current time. Looking at the source code.

Comment: Note that when you edit the expiry date, you need to publish the page again for the new expiry date to take effect - if you only hit 'save', it'll only be counted as a change to the draft version of the page.